# Запрос POST не закончился а страницу уже загрузило Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2

Проблема такая, при открытие модуля у меня сразу выполнятся запрос для информации в select и получается там пусто, но возможно как-то сделать пока запрос не закончился что бы он модуль не отрисовал ?

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gameAccounts();
    this.totalPrice = this.price;

    console.log(this.gameAccountsArray);
    console.log(this.gameAccountsArray[1].account);

  }

  gameAccounts() {
    this.acpService.gameAccounts()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.gameAccountsArray = data.gameAccounts;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Сделайте поле в классе isInit. Выставьте его в false. После того, как выполнится запрос поставьте его в true. В шаблоне оберните весь компонент в ng-container и ngIf с этим полем

Comment: ну за такой вариант я думал, по другому нету да ? нету ивента до загрузки какого можно потом сделать?

Comment: Это был самый простой вариант, можно посмотреть в сторону async-пайпа, возможно с помощью него можно разрулить логику. Можно как-то декомпозировать логику через декомпозицию компонента. Но в любом случае, нужно тогда видеть шаблон. Знать полностью текущий результат и тот, который вы хотите получить. Иначе будет сложно ответить, чтобы получилось просто и эффективно.

Comment: Можно еще воспользоваться resolver-ами, они предназначены для того, чтобы загрузить данные до того, как будет отрисован компонент

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием async-пайпа. Предпочтительней, так как angular сам сделает все необходимые отписки для избежания утечек памяти. Также возможен вариант с тем, чтобы обернуть не весь компонент, а только ту часть, которая ожидает эти данные.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.gameAccountsArray$ = this.gameAccounts();
  ...
}

gameAccounts$() {
  return this.acpService.gameAccounts().pipe(map((data) => data.gameAccounts));
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="gameAccountsArray$ | async">
  ...Остальной код компонента
</div>
```

Также возможно, что не нужно будет оборачивать весь компонент, а передать данные в компонент, который их использует.

```html
<select
[someInput]="gameAccountsArray$ | async"
>
...
</select>
```

Также можно сделать костыльный вариант с использованием флага-инициализации. По сути такой же вариант, что и с `this.gameAccountsArray$`, только сделать специальное поле `initialize`

Comment: Привет, спасибо за подсказку но что-то у меня не выходит :(

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать резолвер на уровне роута. Пока не отработают все резолверы, роут не загрузится.